# How can I replace the "+" plus sign with its corresponding url encoding of "%2B"?

Tags: php, string

I'm having some trouble replacing the "+" sign with its urlencoded string of "%2B".  How can I do this?

This is what I've tried:

Text Entered into text box:

```
plus(+)
```

I then urlencode the string:

```
$string = urlencode($string);
```

String now looks like:

```
plus%28+%29
```

I want to have the "+" urlencoded, or else when I urldecode() the data to display in browser I end up with:

```
plus( )
```

because urldecode() interprets the "+" to be a space.

I tried using php's str_replace() but I keep getting a "NULL" returned as the value for "$new_string":

```
$new_string = str_replace('+', '%2B', $string);
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Using `urlencode($string)` echos `plus%28%2B%29` for me.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

That is strange. When I use `urlencode` on `plus(+)` I get `plus%28%2B%29`. Make sure you're using it correctly.

You might also try [`rawurlencode`](https://www.php.net/rawurlencode). It will encode spaces as `%20` instead of `+`.

Comment: ++ From the comments in the PHP manual page (http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) : "Don't use urlencode() or urldecode() if the text includes an email address, as it destroys the "+" character, a perfectly valid email address character.  Unless you're certain that you won't be encoding email addresses AND you need the readability provided by the non-standard "+" usage, instead always use use rawurlencode() or rawurldecode(). "

Comment: I had the same issue and it was really hard to debug, the problem is that htaccess automatically decodes the params, you have to use the `[B]` flag as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48543854/407650

Answer (score 2):

That helped me:

```
function _rawurlencode($string) {
    $string = rawurlencode(str_replace('+','%2B',$string));
    return $string;
}
```