# PHP: rawurldecode() not showing plus sign

Tags: php, urldecode

I have a URL like this:

```
abc.com/my+string
```

When I get the parameter, it obviously it replaces the `+` with a space, so I get `my string`

I replaced the `+` in the url with `%2B`, then I use `rawurldecode()`, but the result is the same. Tried with `urldecode()` but I still can't get the `plus sign` in my variable, it's always an empty space.

Am I missing something, how do I get exactly `my+string` in PHP from the url `abc.com/my%2Bstring` ?

Thank you

Comment: _“then I use rawurldecode()”_ - on what exact value, gotten from where/how? What was that value before you applied rawurldecode?

Comment: I thought it was obvious. On the $_GET parameter. abc.com?var=my%2Bstring

Comment: Your example did not even _have_ GET parameters, so much for "obvious" ... And since when do we URL-decode GET parameter values manually? We don’t, since PHP has already done that for us. `abc.com?var=my%2Bstring` -> $_GET['var']  will contain `my+string`

Comment: Sorry about that. That url is re-written by htaccess, and when I get the var param, it returns always with a space instead of the plus sign. Tried with all the decode functions but it's the same. Do you know if re-writing with htaccess can cause this ? Thank you

Comment: Yes, the rewriting could easily be the issue here - the `B` flag exists to prevent such issues, see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_b

Comment: @CBroe That was it! Thank you so much. I added the B flag and know it works as expected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, you don’t need to URL-decode GET parameter values manually, since PHP already does that for you, automatically. `abc.com?var=my%2Bstring` -> `$_GET['var']` will contain `my+string`

The problem here was that URL rewriting was in play. As http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_b explains,

> mod_rewrite has to unescape URLs before mapping them, so backreferences will be unescaped at the time they are applied.

So mod_rewrite has decoded `my%2Bstring` to `my+string`, and when you rewrite this as a query string parameter, you effectively get `?var=my+string`. And when PHP applies automatic URL decoding on *that* value, the `+` will become a simple space.

The `[B]` flag exists to make mod_rewrite re-encode the value again.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
echo urldecode("abc.com/my%2Bstring");      // => abc.com/my+string
echo PHP_EOL;
echo rawurldecode("abc.com/my%2Bstring");   // => abc.com/my+string
```

Further if you want to get the actual `my+string`, you can utilize the powers of [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) function which comes with PHP itself, although you have to provide a full URL into it.

Other way is just to [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) the value by a `/` and get it like this:

```
$parts = explode('/', 'abc.com/my+string'); // => Array(2)
echo $parts[1] ?? 'not found';              // => string|not found
```

Also read the documentation on both: [urldecode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) and [rawurldecode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rawurldecode.php).

[Example here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ad81080d269082fc50478652797defc9dc1fbbe4).

Comment: I had to use explode in the end, do you know if rewriting with htaccess can cause this ? Because using the decode functions does not work, it always return the string with a space instead of the plus sign. Thank you

Comment: I doubt it. But provide us with more information on your web server, PHP configuration, how do you receive that link, etc. so we might be able to help you more.

Comment: The full link is like this www.site.com/coupons/email-address (www.site.com/coupons?email=xxxx).  Basically I am creating some coupons for the provided email address, but when using the + sign in the email address, it saves it with a space instead in the DB. Using php 7.1 if that helps. Unfortunately the link is created by a third-party website, on which I do not have any control.

Comment: Thank you for the help, it was indeed because of the htaccess. Had to add the B flag.